# Problemas instalando CPANM - Perl

Tags: perl, cpan

Estoy intentando instalar el modulo de cpanm tal como indica la pagina de CPAN

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
install cpanm
```

Pero me esta generando el siguiente error, busqué en la web y no consigue nada de utilidad.

```html
cpan[1]> install cpanm
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sat, 31 Aug 2019 10:55:18 GMT
Warning: Cannot install cpanm, don't know what it is.
Try the command

    i /cpanm/

to find objects with matching identifiers.

cpan[2]>
```

Tambien estoy intentando instalar la libreria Mail::Box y luego de ejecutar los comandos que indica CPAN me sigue dando el error de que debo instalar la libreria

S.O: GNU/Linux CentOS 6.9

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta de instalarlo es a través de:

```
curl -L https://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus
```

Espero les sea de utilidad

Comment: Resuelto también en http://perlenespanol.com/foro/instalacion-de-modulos-y-bibliotecas-en-perl-t7875.html